# C++, Java, Swig, shared_ptrs and templated classes

Tags: java, c++, c++11, swig, shared-ptr

I have a C++ class structure like this:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual int getValue1();
}

template<typename DATATYPE>
class BaseT : public Base {
  public:
    virtual DATATYPE getValue2();
}

class Derived1 : public BaseT<char> {
  public:
    char getValue2();
}

class Derived2 : public BaseT<std::string> {
  public:
    std::string getValue2();
}
```

For the sake of this example please assume that both values 1 and 2 are initialized in the constructor of the derived classes by whatever algorithm.

I have a container class that internally holds a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>` that contains both `Derived1` and `Derived2` instances.

The container class also has the following three functions:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> getAllInstances();
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived1>> getDerived1Instances();
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived2>> getDerived2Instances();
```

In an earlier version of the C++ code, these functions simply returned vectors of instances, not vectors of pointers to instances (same three functions, just returning e.g. `std::vector<Base>`).

I was successfully able to generate a working Java interface for those functions by using the following SWIG directives (I left out the `#include`s for simplicity):

```
%include "std_vector.i"
%template(BaseList) std::vector<Base>;
%template(Derived1List) std::vector<Derived1>;
%template(Derived2List) std::vector<Derived2>;

%include "Base.h"
%include "BaseT.h"

%template(Derived1) BaseT<char>;
%template(Derived2) BaseT<std::string>;

%include "Derived1.h"
%include "Derived2.h"
```

But now, since I changed the function return types, I can't get my Java code to work again.

**I tried the following SWIG directives:**

```
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_shared_ptr.i"

%template(BasePtr) std::shared_ptr<Base>;
%template(Derived1Ptr) std::shared_ptr<Derived1>;
%template(Derived2Ptr) std::shared_ptr<Derived2>;

%template(BaseList) std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>;
%template(Derived1List) std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived1>>;
%template(Derived2List) std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived2>>;

%include "Base.h"
%include "BaseT.h"

%template(Derived1) BaseT<char>;
%template(Derived2) BaseT<std::string>;

%include "Derived1.h"
%include "Derived2.h"
```

SWIG runs without warnings, the generated .cpp-file compiles and the .java-files are generated aswell.

Problem: My instances of e.g. `Derived1List` only contain `Derived1Ptr` instances and those do not contain any methods to access the actual data - the only public method of `Derived1Ptr` is `delete`.

**Next step:** I tried to add `%shared_ptr`.

```
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_shared_ptr.i"

%shared_ptr(Derived1)
%shared_ptr(Derived2)

/* ... templates and includes as above ... */
```

This results in SWIG producing warnings about the classes `Base` and `BaseT` not being marked as smart pointers, but the .cpp-file still compiles.

The `Derived1List` now contains `Derived1`-instances again that I can use to access the actual data (perfect!), but the Java program crashes with an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` whenever I try to access `derived1.getValue1()` (not perfect at all...) - `derived1.getValue2()` works fine.

**Next step:** Also throw in `%shared_ptr(Base)`

Result: The warning about `Base` not being marked as smart pointer is gone, the one about `BaseT` is obviously still there.

The .cpp-file does not compile anymore:

```
swig_wrapper.cpp: In function 'void Java_swig_mytestlibJNI_delete_1Derived1(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong)':
swig_wrapper.cpp:2000:26: error: 'smartarg1' was not declared in this scope
   (void)arg1; delete smartarg1;
                      ^
```

**Next step:** Also throw in `%shared_ptr(BaseT)`

Result: SWIG does not print any warnings.
The .cpp-file does not compile anymore and outputs a **lot** of errors similar to `expected a type, got 'BaseT'`.

So - my question is, how should my definition file look like in order to make vectors of shared pointers work? What am I missing?